# Filtering data with Proc SQL

Tags: sql, sas

I am trying to perform some linear regression for a dataset on SAS using SQL to manipulate the data.

But that data needs to be split into 2 tables based on non smokers and smokers. So I have use SQL to convert Boolean field into a numeric.

But I am not able to split the table into two with a criteria.

```
/* Filtering Non Smockers and Adding 10 to age */
proc sql;
create table library.smoker_num as
select risk,Age,Pressure,Smoker,age+10 as age_plus,Pressure+10 as bp_plus,Pressure+(Pressure/10) as bp_prec,
case when Smoker='No' then 0 else 1
end as smoker_num

from library.smoking_r;

quit;
/* The above code is working fine*/

/* Left joining the filtered datatable to main table */
proc sql;
title "Final Table";
create table library.finaltable_nonsmoker 

where Smoker='No'
/*I am getting error for this where statement*/
from library.smoker_num;

quit;
```

I expect to see the table divided based on smoking criteria.

Comment: The syntax of SQL is `SELECT` --> `FROM` --> `WHERE`.  I can't figure out what you want to actually do, but it does occur to me that a data step would also work.

Comment: I need to select rows where Smoker is given as 'No' and store that data in a separate table. And yes I am following Select -> From-> Where. Thanks for the help

Comment: if your regression step requires two data sets, use the data set option `where` to restrict the rows selected, no splitting required.  `... data1=have(where=(where-clause-1)) data2=have(where=(where-clause-2)) … ;`

Comment: `proc sql` expects valid SQL statement. Your first is valid but not second. Please try appropriately adding `SELECT` and re-order of `FROM` and `WHERE`.

Comment: Thanks Richard, I tried you method and it worked. I really not sure why my SQL is not working as expected. I will get back to this thread once I find out why. Thank you everyone.

Comment: Why not just sort the data by SMOKER and run your regression code with BY SMOKER to get a separate regression for each level of SMOKER variable?

Comment: Why do you think your need to create a numeric variable with 0 and 1 values instead of the existing variable with YES and NO values?

Answer (score 0):

Your posted code:

```
/* Left joining the filtered datatable to main table */
proc sql;
title "Final Table";
create table library.finaltable_nonsmoker 

where Smoker='No'
/*I am getting error for this where statement*/
from library.smoker_num;

quit;
```

Note that in your code you have the WHERE before FROM, you need to switch the order of those statements, as indicated by /u/Gordon in his first comment.

```
/* Left joining the filtered datatable to main table */
proc sql;
title "Final Table";
create table library.finaltable_nonsmoker 

<Insert select statement>

/*I am getting error for this where statement*/

from library.smoker_num

where Smoker='No';

quit;
```

However, SAS regression procedures support a CLASS statement which usually means you don't need to convert a categorical variable and I'm not sure how splitting the data helps. If you need to run separate regression models for the smoking criteria just use a BY statement on the SMOKER variable or use a WHERE statement within the regression to limit the dataset, you don't need the intermediate data sets.

Comment: Interesting, so you do not need a `select` statement in `proc sql`?

Comment: @Parfait . . . Well, you could have `update` or `delete`.  I think Reeza missed that.

Comment: You create a zero-rowed copy of a table using `like` (and no `select`).  Example: `create table work.class like sashelp.class`